# why does my button disappear when I add the toggle event in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to toggle text between bold and normal I made this code for it, but when I open my page the bold button disappears?

```
    $("#bold").toggle(function() {
    $('.focus').css("font-weight", $(this).val());
    }, function() {
    $('.focus').css("font-weight", "normal");
    });
```

Is there something wrong with my code?
Please help, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It disappears because that version of toggle is deprecated and removed, and in newer versions of jQuery all it does is toggle visibility.

You could do something like this instead :

```
var state = true;

$("#bold").on('click', function() {
    $('.focus').css("font-weight", state ? this.value : 'normal');
    state = !state;
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/6jYRk/)

Comment: Yes that works. If its no big bother to you would you mind to explain a little to me on how that worked? I want to learn why it functions and not just copy your code. For instance the '?' its asking if the state is true or false? or how?

Comment: The `if ? do this : or this` is a fancy if/else called a ternary statement, so it toggles the value based on wether or not the `state` is true or false, and `state = !state` (state equals **not** state) flips the value on each click, in effect toggling.

Answer (score 7):

Assuming you're using jQuery 1.9 or later the problem is that the [`.toggle()` event handling method](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/) was *removed* from the library. So what you're actually calling is the [`.toggle()` function that hides/shows elements](http://api.jquery.com/toggle). (In earlier versions of jQuery both functions existed and jQuery figured out which one you meant based on the arguments passed in.)

You can implement your own toggle easily enough with a standard `.click()` handler:

```
$("#bold").click(function() {
   var f = !$(this).data("toggleFlag");
   if (f) {
      $('.focus').css("font-weight", $(this).val());
   } else {
      $('.focus').css("font-weight", "normal");
   }
   $(this).data("toggleFlag", f);
});
```

This uses the [`.data()` method](http://api.jquery.com/data) to keep track of a boolean flag to indicate which code to execute. The very first time the click handler is called the flag will be returned as `undefined` because it hasn't previously been set, but we just convert that to a boolean with `!` (assuming you want to execute the if and not the else case on the first click).

Comment: Oohh, hmm that sucks :/ Is there a different way to do it? to make it toggle?

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I fount to the disappearing element after click... is Callback function after the toggle effect finished.
here a link that explain the [Callback function](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_callback.asp).

and here is my code:

```
jQuery('.menu li.item-487').click(function(){
        jQuery('#main-menu .moduletable .menu li').toggle("slow",function(){jQuery('.menu li.item-487').css('display' , 'block');});

    });
```